# Kubernetes Ingress needs Reverse Proxy setting

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, node-red, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

In my Kubernetes Cluster i have some challenges with the Ingress. As example i installed NodeRed und the Nginx-ingress via Helm. NodeRed is available via

- FQDN: http://my.server.name:31827
- IP: http://10.x.x.x:31827

Now i created an Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nr-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret1
    hosts:
    - my.server.name
  rules:
  - host: my.server.name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nr
        backend:
          serviceName: my-nodered-node-red
          servicePort: 1880
```

When i do a Get http://my.server.name/nr i see only parts working, see the screenshot:

[image]

It looks to me, that i missed the reverse proxy settings. Normally i would place those things in a reverse proxy setting in the nginx like this. But this is not possible because i am using the Nginx-ingress.

```
location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:1880/;
    }
```

But i do not know how to do that in Kubernetes ? What do i miss ? kubernetes version is 1.14.1.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it so I'm not sure if it helps, but you might want to try adding an annotation for [Proxy redirect](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#proxy-redirect).

> With the annotations  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from`  and  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to`  it is possible to set the text that should be changed in the  `Location`  and  `Refresh`  header fields of a  [proxied server response](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)
>
> Setting "off" or "default" in the annotation  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from`  disables  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to`, otherwise, both annotations must be used in unison. Note that each annotation must be a string without spaces.
>
> By default the value of each annotation is "off".

Also you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) for customizing your Nginx configuration.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
data:

  http-snippet: |
      location = / {       
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1880/;
      }
```

Or [`server-snippets`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) annotation for your `Ingress`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nr-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location = / {       
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1880/;
      }
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret1
    hosts:
    - my.server.name
  rules:
  - host: my.server.name
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /nr
        backend:
          serviceName: my-nodered-node-red
          servicePort: 1880
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. I tried that, but thanks for your help. Maybe i will have a lucky find in the next days :-)

Comment: @Mchoeti, this should work as stated on nginx documentation. Are You getting errors or this just doesn't work? Maybe it's like Vasily Angapov said.

Comment: Was looking for simple proxy_pass solution, the second solution worked well. Didn't even need to try the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late for the answer, but I had the same problem and solve it:

1-changed httpRoot: '/nr' in node red settings.xml configuration file (in kubernetes, probably defined in a PV) (@vasili-angapov mentions)

2- set ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nodered-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /nr
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nodered
                port:
                  number: 1880
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your static content is still using root path prefix, you can verify that using browser developer console. Common applications should have a configuration to understand that they are running on non-root path prefix. You should find that configuration option in your application and configure it properly. Nginx ingress has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: hm..  But when i set up an NGINX config like that location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:1880/;
    } it is working. My question was how to do this in Kubernetes

Comment: because you specify root path prefix (location /). In ingress you are specifying non-root path prefix (/nr), see the difference?

Comment: yes, i see the difference, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem